# How to recognize which button from tkinter is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to code a TicTacToe game with the tkinter module.
My problem is that I have nine buttons on my canvas and when they are clicked they should change their image to the cross or the circle. But for this function, I have to know which button was clicked so that I can change the image of the right one.

So my question is: How can I recognize which button was clicked? (I'm pretty new to Python)

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

#---------------------------------------Definitions-------------------------------------------------

def startgame():
    global whois
    whois = 1
    turn.place(x=413, y=150)
    Player1.place(x=10, y=5)
    Player2.place(x=10, y=45)
    PlayerCross.place(x=150, y=52)
    PlayerCircle.place(x=150, y=10)
    A1.place(x=158, y=204, width=223, height=228)
    A2.place(x=387, y=204, width=232, height=228)
    A3.place(x=626, y=204, width=225, height=228)
    B1.place(x=158, y=438, width=223, height=232)
    B2.place(x=387, y=438, width=232, height=232)
    B3.place(x=626, y=438, width=225, height=232)
    C1.place(x=158, y=675, width=223, height=226)
    C2.place(x=387, y=675, width=232, height=226)
    C3.place(x=626, y=675, width=225, height=226)
    startscreen.place_forget()
    start.place_forget()



def turnimage():
    global whois
    if whois == 1:
        turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"
        A3["image"] = circle
        whois = 2
    else:
        turn["text"] = "Player 2's turn!"
        A3["image"] = cross
        whois = 1

#---------------------------------------------variables-------------------------------------------------------

background = tk.PhotoImage(file = "TicTacToe_bg.png")
standartTexture = tk.PhotoImage(file = "standartTexture.png")
cross = tk.PhotoImage(file = "cross.png")
circle = tk.PhotoImage(file = "circle.png")
PlayerCrossImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "PlayerCross.png")
PlayerCircleImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "PlayerCircle.png")


whois = 0
field = tk.Label(root, image = background)
turn = tk.Label(root, text = " ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
Player1 = tk.Label(root, text = "Player 1 = ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
Player2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Player 2 = ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
PlayerCross = tk.Label(root, image = PlayerCrossImage, bd = 0)
PlayerCircle = tk.Label(root, image = PlayerCircleImage, bd = 0)
startscreen = tk.Label(root, text = "", height = 500, width = 500, bg = "#FFFFFF")
start = tk.Button(root, text = "Start", font = "Ariel 50", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", command = startgame)


A1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
A2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
A3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = turnimage)
B1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
B2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
B3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
C1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
C2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)
C3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0)

#--------------------------------------------place stuff-----------------------------------------------------------------

startscreen.place(x = 148, y = 195)
field.pack()
start.place(x = 400, y = 400)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For each button, something like `A1["command"] = lambda: turnimage(A1)` - now your function receives a parameter specifying the button that was clicked.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add a parameter to the function (since it's now being called with one), and use that instead of your currently hard-coded `A3` in the function.

Comment: I have one more question: I tried to "lock" the field where a player had already placed a cross or circle so this can't be changed anymore like this:

Comment: def turnimage(a):
    global whois
    if whois == 1 and a["image"] == standartTexture:
        turn["text"] = "Player 2's turn!"
        a["image"] = circle
        whois = 2
    elif whois == 2 and a["image"] == standartTexture:
        turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"
        a["image"] = cross
        whois = 1
    else:
        error.place(x = 330, y = 920)

Comment: but always when i try it the else statement gets executed

Comment: Reading back the `image` option gives you the name of the image, rather than the image object itself - so you have to write that comparison as `a["image"] == str(standartTexture)".